# "fputs(): send of 8192 bytes failed with errno=32" Is it me, or the destination server?

Tags: php

I'm receiving the following notice when sending an array of bytes via an API, using PHP & NuSOAP.

> fputs(): send of 8192 bytes failed with errno=32 Broken pipe in nusoap.php on line 2900

This is the only API method I've used so far that has given me this notice.

The data that I'm sending is also all received, in a complete and usable format by the destination server.

I can't really find a lot on the internet about this error, and the occurrences of it that I do come across are mainly related to sending mail.

I did see one answer, which said it was the destination server closing the connection before the write operation finished. However, I'm not certain of that.

Does anyone have any any information on what the notice actually is? Such as whether the cause is on my side, or the other side of the API.

Comment: `broken pipe` = network error. something killed the connection (probably the other side) and php hasn't realized it yet. trying to send/receive on a dead connection will cause this error. Check the remote mail server's logs to see if there's anything there on why it severed the connection.

Comment: I don't have access to the remote servers logs as such. As I'm only connecting to the remote server via the API. So it's a hard one to try and work out...

Comment: you could try doing teh http request manually, e.g. building your soap request in php, dumping out the actual contents of the request, then doing something like telnetting to port 80 on the server and manually issuing the request. might get more information out of it that way.